# QTableWidget grid doesn't fill the widget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have created a simple QTableWidget, set StretchLastSection to true on the horizontal header, which works fine.

It however looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there is a little spacing after the last cell so the grid border doesn't line up with the header.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like a spacing in the layout. Are you sure that there are no property `layoutHorizontalSpacing==6` or something like this?

Comment: Not 100% sure I follow. This is a QtableWidget. I cant add a layout to a QTableWidget, or?

Comment: No, I expect your QTableWidget is placed in a layout. Anyway, add more information about the problem: How do you create the table? How do you add the table on the dialog?